# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while submitting spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am facing error while submitting spark job:

[image]

What could be the cause for this?
I am submitting spark job through:

```
/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit \
--class com.pkg.ml.models.ML \
--master yarn-cluster \
--driver-memory 8G \
--executor-memory 2G \
--num-executors 100 \
--files ml.properties \
--jars /current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar,/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.1.0-129.jar,/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
spark-ml-0.0.2.jar ml.properties $1 $2
rc=$?

if (( $rc )); then

    echo "Job failed" 1>&2

    exit $rc

fi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your spark version installed.
This error occurs mainly due to the different versions of spark.
Make sure that spark version on your system and spark client both should be same.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible it needs to be updated in the VM. It's included in the VM purely as a convenience - as it's not an officially supported or included part of CDH it doesn't go through all the same testing as everything else.